# I want to post the information obtained using the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to send the value obtained by the API changed by the method to the server by post. What is the correct answer in this case? I've been researching this for about 3 days.
I want to use the values ​​obtained by the "title", "author", and "image" methods.

ex)

```
 postBook () {
      this.$axios.$post('/api/v1/posts', {
        post: {
          title: ???,　title(selectedBook）
          author: ???,　authors(selectedBook）
          image: ???  image(selectedBook)
        }
      })
```

I want to do this

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card
      width="900px"
      min-height="400px"
      class="mx-auto my-8 pa-3 rounded-xl"
    >
      <div style="height:100px;">
        <v-card-subtitle v-if="selectedBook == null">

        </v-card-subtitle>
        <template v-if="selectedBook != null">
          <v-row style="text-align:center;">
            <v-col cols="6" class="pa-5">
              <img :src="image(selectedBook)">
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="4" class="pa-5">
              <v-card-title>{{ title(selectedBook) }}</v-card-title>
              <v-card-subtitle class="pa-3">
                {{ authors(selectedBook) }}
              </v-card-subtitle>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </template>
      </div>
      <BookPostText />
      <v-divider
        class="ma-7"
      />
      <v-row
        justify="center"
        class="ma-5"
      >
        <v-btn
          color="success"
          class="ma-2"
          @click="postBook"
        >
          登録する
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          class="ma-2"
          depressed
          @click="clearBook()"
        >
          やめる
        </v-btn>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import noImage from '~/assets/images/noImage.png'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedBook () {
      return this.$store.state.selectedBook
    }
  },

  methods: {
    title: valu => valu.volumeInfo.title ? valu.volumeInfo.title : 'No title',
    authors: valu => valu.volumeInfo.authors ? valu.volumeInfo.authors[0] : 'No authors',
    image: valu => valu.volumeInfo.imageLinks ? valu.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : noImage,
    clearBook () {
      this.$store.commit('clearBook')
    },
    postBook () {
      this.$axios.$post('/api/v1/posts', {
        post: {
          title: ???,
          author: ???,
          image: ???
        }
      })
        .then(response => this.$store.commit('userBook', response))
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
img {
  height: 120px;
}
</style>
```

environment
　- Nuxt.js 2.15

- Ruby on Rails 6

Comment: You should probably use `title`, `author` and `image` as computed and pass them in the form of `title: this.title` for your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component's methods and properties would be accessed as a property of `this`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    postBook () {
      this.$axios.$post('/api/v1/posts', {
        post: {
          title: this.title(this.selectedBook),
          author: this.authors(this.selectedBook),
          image: this.image(this.selectedBook),
        }
      }).then(response => this.$store.commit('userBook', response))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.There was such an easy way. I was thinking hard